# How do I troubleshoot decrypting this OpenPGP.js message?

Tags: openpgp.js

I have a string message called customerPublicKey which I encrypted with OpenPGP.js:

```
    const { customerPublicKey} = await openpgp.generateKey({
      type: 'rsa',
      passphrase: contract.passphrase,
      userIDs: [{ name: 'My Name', email: 'name@example.com' }]
    });

    const message = await openpgp.createMessage({text: 'stringKey'});
    const encrypted = await openpgp.encrypt({
        message, // input as Message object
        encryptionKeys: customerPublicKey
    });
```

I'm trying to decrypt it with OpenPGP.js, like this:

```
    const buyerEncryptedKey = await openpgp.readMessage({
      armoredMessage: encrypted 
    })
    const { privateKey  } = await openpgp.generateKey({
      type: 'rsa',
      passphrase: passphrase.value,
      userIDs: [{ name: 'My Name', email: 'name@example.com' }]
    });

    const decryptionKeys = await openpgp.decryptKey({
        privateKey: await openpgp.readPrivateKey({armoredKey:privateKey}),
        passphrase: passphrase.value 
    })
```

This is throwing the following error:

> error:  Error: Error decrypting message: Session key decryption failed.

What do I need to do to debug this? Does anyone have insight here?

Answer (score 1):

That error is because your code is wrong. Your `privateKey` -- returned from `openpgp.generateKey` -- is the externalized (encrypted, serialized and armored) form of the key, but `openpgp.decrypt` wants the internal (JS-object) form; to get that you need to read back and decrypt the external form like this:

```
    const { data } = await openpgp.decrypt({
      message: buyerEncryptedKey,
      //decryptionKeys: privateKey
      decryptionKeys: await openpgp.decryptKey({privateKey: await openpgp.readPrivateKey({armoredKey:privateKey}),passphrase: whatevervalue })
    });
```

However, that gives a *different* error:

```
Error: Error decrypting message: Session key decryption failed.
    at Eh.decryptSessionKeys (/node_modules/openpgp/dist/node/openpgp.min.js:2:338991)
    at async Eh.decrypt (/node_modules/openpgp/dist/node/openpgp.min.js:2:336097)
    at async Object.exports.decrypt (/node_modules/openpgp/dist/node/openpgp.min.js:16:132527)
    at async [stdin]:30:22
```

because your *design* is wrong. You can only decrypt a publickey-encrypted message using the privatekey that MATCHES the publickey -- i.e. the other half of the same keypair, created by the same key-generation operation. Generating a *new* keypair as you do here creates a keypair that is different from all keypairs in existence anywhere in the world, and that includes the keypair whose publickey you (or someone) used to encrypt your message. Since the generated key is different from the correct key, it cannot decrypt the message.

Comment: But I am generating this new keypair with the same inputs as I did the original one.

Comment: Meaning, at some point prior the buyer entered a passphrase, from which I generated a keypair and stored the public key, with which I encrypted the buyer's key. If during this session I get the buyer's passphrase and generate another keypair with the same inputs as the original, I should be able to decrypt with the private key, right?

Comment: I updated the example code to more clearly show what I'm trying to do

Comment: Boris: A PGP keypair is not generated 'from' the passphrase. The keypair is generated at random, then the privatekey (only) is _encrypted_ under the passphrase. (Or to be exact, under a symmetric key derived from the passphrase using an 's2k' = string-to-key algorithm.) That's why you must supply the same passphrase to `decryptKey`. Doing another `generateKey` does NOT recreate the same keypair; as I said, every generation creates a completely new and unique keypair that doesn't match any previously existing keypair, and thus doesn't work to decrypt your data.

Comment: PS: if what you want is to encrypt _data_ under a password and decrypt with the same password, you don't use any keypair; you instead use PGP's 'symmetric' mode (technically, [packet tag 3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880.html#section-5.3)). See e.g. https://www.npmjs.com/package/openpgp#encrypt-symmetrically-with-compression .

Comment: But I specifically want to allow the buyer to supply the public key and the seller to encrypt data using that public key, and then the buyer to decrypt with his private key. I guess I will just save the encrypted private key and then return to the buyer for decryption with his passphrase.